Web AudioContext blocks other apps audio
I'm making an web app to analyze the device's mic input (cell phone the most) while the same device is playing music from other native app (spotifty, youtube whatever) to an external audio device. The cell phone mic listen to the audio itself is playing, basically, comming from the audio device connected. But since I initiate the AudioContext it blocks other apps to send audio. Is there any chance I could connect things such a way it doesen't happen? Same problem on desktop.
